# My UserModel is not returning the proper user data finding _id?

Tags: javascript, mongoose

This is my code:

```
var user = UserModel.findOne({ _id: decodedToken.id, }, function (err, user) {
                  if (err) return handleError(err)
                  console.log('inside UserModel user = ', user) // this is what I want to return on the variable user
                });

console.log("Outside userModel = ",user) // the user inside the findOne callback isn't assigned on the variable user?
```

Inside the UserModel.findOne callback it returns the proper user:

```
{ _id: 5979744a02bcec1dc873a96c,
  updatedAt: 2017-07-27T05:04:10.313Z,
  createdAt: 2017-07-27T05:04:10.313Z,
  fullName: 'kring kring',
  email: 'sofbaculio@gmail.com',
  password: '$2a$08$yiDO.HBGoieBApY8VCHA/Opp6PEpq7.CwZmfc2CkQmQoRfB/ySi4u',
  __v: 0,
  active: true }
```

but outside the callback it returns something like this:

```
 Query {
  _mongooseOptions: {},
  mongooseCollection:
   NativeCollection {
     collection: Collection { s: [Object] },
     opts: { bufferCommands: true, capped: false },
     name: 'user',
```

Help?

Answer (score 1):

Thats because your function actually returns a Mongoose query which you can later use to invoke the method exec and use it to get the results.

You need to now execute that Query to get the results:

```
user.exec(function(err,result){
   if(err)
      return console.log(err);
   console.log(result);
});
```

You can read more about Querying with Mongoose @ http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html

Comment: it's still the same, can you make an answer with my code? I tried user.exec() below the query, still not working.

Comment: Did you receive an error when you ran exec? What did it output to the console?

Comment: no error but it returns this:
 Promise {
  emitter:
   EventEmitter {
     domain: null,
     _events: {},
     _eventsCount: 0,
     _maxListeners: undefined },
  emitted: {},
  ended: false }

Comment: I tried var user = UserModel.findOne({ _id: decodedToken.id, }).exec() still the same, not working

Comment: After than above statement use `.then`, e.g. `UserModel.findOne({ _id: decodedToken.id, }).exec().then(function(result) { });` . Since the query is async, it returns a promise when at some point will proc the function passed to then

Comment: I tried reassigning on .then but still not working :(

Answer (score 0):

Well the issue is its a async call so in that case you have to implement a promise to achieve this.

Also if you are going to find in model using mongo Object Id which is _id then you should go for UserModel.findById(decodedToken.id) instead of UserModel.findOne({ _id: decodedToken.id, }. Just try it and next time when you want to query a collection by Object Id just go for Model.findById its a good practice. hope it helps.

Comment: I have posted a code for you check it out and try to learn about javascript promises. What are promises and how they works.

Answer (score 0):

ok follow these steps one by one I am trying my best to help you.

First you need to install q library to implement promise. you can install it by using

`npm install q`.

```
    getUser(decodedToken.id).then(function(res){
    console.log(res);
    var user = res;
    //Just do it here what ever you want to do 
    },function(err){
    console.log(err)
    })

    //Here is your promise that you going to return
    function getUser(id) {
    return Q.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    UserModel.findById(decodedToken.id), function (err, user) {
                  if (err) return reject(err)
                  console.log('inside UserModel user = ', user)
                  resolve(user)
                });
     })
    }
```